# Correctly Serving imported pdf files in DSpace

Tags: tomcat, pdf, data-migration, dspace

I have manually imported a DSpace repository from one website to another, installing the same old version 3.2 to prevent database version problems. Importing configuration files and the assetstore folder. On **CentOS** with **Apache** and **Tomcat**.

Everything works right except downloading/viewing pdf files attached to articles. They start downloading and then get stuck at some point. Some pdf readers show the first pages and others just a blank window, but all of them claim something like *this could not be printed* so that they detect something is going wrong.

I checked that pdf files themselves are ok. And that they are copied to the correct bitstream location which appears in the database. I tried as well to chown and chmod to several logical values (orginal files where owned by `tomcat6`, but `tomcat6` and `tomcat7` do not exist in  my system so I tried `dspace`, `root`, 777 permissions...) and the problem remains. File size is not a problem either (I tested and size is not relevant). There is only one asset store in this repository.

In the other hand, files that I upload to the new repository through the webapp user interface work perfectly. I looked for differences between working and crashing uploaded files from command line and with Firebug and everything seems to be the same.

What else could I check?

Comment: Strange problem! Do they all get stuck downloading at the same point, e.g. after a specific filesize? 

Could you verify that the size of the asset store folder on your old repository stayed the same in the old and new repository? 

If you state "imported", how have you done the import process (which scripts?)

Comment: @BramLuyten At first I thought it was some kid of download limitation. Then I realised the limit was not always the same. Neither is it a fixed percentage of the file size.

Comment: @BramLuyten The new assetstore folder is a bit bigger. This difference sounds good to me because of the new test pdf files I uploaded.

Comment: @BramLuyten I imported the assetstore folder by downloading it to my local computer via FTP, then uploading to a temporal folder on the new server and copying it with sudo cp to the final destination. First ownership was then root:root. Dates were lost.

Comment: Tough issue, hard to judge whether the error is happening on the server or client side. Assuming server side, since you mention that new uploaded files just work well. Is there any additional information in your dspace logfile or tomcat logfiles around the time you try a download for one of those files that fail?

Comment: @BramLuyten Well... Now it just works... ¿? The only change I think that could affect is that I am using a domain and not just an IP. But I don't understand what is happening...